# Passing parameter in inner html in java script

Tags: javascript

I want pass parameter in inner html.

```
function func() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("section");
    var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
    ul.appendChild(newLI);
    var ch = 'kuldeep';
    newLI.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='itemcustom(ch)'>Click Me </a>";
}
```

Please advice how to add parameter in itemcustom function right now it is not taking any parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break the string literal, to insert the variable `ch` as such:

```
function func() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("section");
    var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
    ul.appendChild(newLI);
    var ch = 'kuldeep';
    newLI.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='itemcustom("+ ch +")'>Click Me </a>";
}
```

This is called `string concatenation`, which means adding two or more strings together as one.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it's rendering as text. You'll have to escape the string like so:

```
"<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='itemcustom("+ch+")'>Click Me </a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a proper element ?

```
function func() {
    var ul     = document.getElementById("section");
    var newLI  = document.createElement("li");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    var ch     = 'kuldeep';

    anchor.href = "#";
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
        itemcustom(ch);
        return false;
    }, false);
    anchor.innerHTML = 'Click Me';

    newLI.appendChild(anchor);
    ul.appendChild(newLI);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2SX8V/)